# PowerShell does not replace string although you can see it in cmd

Tags: string, matlab, powershell, replace

I normally find the answer to my problem by going through the site, but this time I have read every question yet still I am in despair and really need an experienced eye.

What I have is basically a structural health monitoring system. I measure strains and receive raw data. This raw data is processed by a MATLAB executable that I wrote myself and then uploaded to an ftp-server. We had a student that automated this with a PowerShell script which was working perfectly until I changed literally one small line in MATLAB and recompiled the code.

I do not understand much about PowerShell, so please be patient with me. The error I receive is `you cannot call a method on a null-valued expression`. This occurs when I try to replace a set of strings (just called xxx_xxx) with a date that exists as a variable in PowerShell. I can see xxx_xxx in the command window (see attached image), I can print out the date that I want to use as replacement, but somehow it does not work.

I cannot provide a working code snippet because you would need the DAQ to generate data, and as I said, I don't understand the language much. But below is the code. For easier reading, the line that I am receiving the error is the following:

```html
$outData = $cmdOutput.Replace("xxx_xxx",$snaps[$i].Substring(6,4)+"-"+$snaps[$i].Substring(3,2)+"-"+$snaps[$i].Substring(0,2)+" "+$snaps[$i].Substring(11,8)+";")
```

[image]

If anyone could help me with this, I would be eternally grateful!

```html
$retry=3
while(1){
#$dir = "C:\Users\Petar\Documents\Zoo\PetarData\INPUT DATA\New folder\"
$dir = "C:\Users\Yunus\Documents\Micron Optics\ENLIGHT\Data\" + $(get-date -f yyyy) + "\" + $(get-date -f MM) + "\"
#$outdir = "C:\Users\Petar\Documents\Zoo\PetarData\OUTPUT DATA\New folder\"
$archivedirin = "C:\Users\Yunus\Documents\Elefantenhaus\Archive\IN\"
$archivedirout = "C:\Users\Yunus\Documents\Elefantenhaus\Archive\OUT\"
$tempdir = "C:\Users\Yunus\Documents\Elefantenhaus\Archive\TEMP\"
$prefix = "EHZZ";

$filecount=(Get-ChildItem $dir).Count

$latest = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1

 if($filecount -gt 1){
 
  $exclude = $latest.name
  $Files = GCI -path $dir | Where-object {$_.name -ne $exclude} 
  $dest = $archivedirin + "batch_"+$(get-date -f MM-dd-yyyy_HH_mm_ss)+"\"
  new-item -type directory $dest
  
  foreach ($file in $Files){move-item -path ($dir+$file) -destination $dest}
  
  $latest = Get-ChildItem -Path $dest | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
  $filename = $dest + $latest.name
  $s=Get-Content $filename
  while($s -eq $null){
   if($retry -lt 0){break}
   write-host "could not read file"
   $retry = $retry -1
   $s=Get-Content $filename
  
  }
  
  #read content of input file
  $snaps = $s

  #loop through the lines in the file until the first occurence of a timestamp, that is our desired line
  for ($i = 0; $i -lt $snaps.length; $i++)
   {
   
    $ismatch =[regex]::Matches($snaps[$i], '^(\d\d.\d\d.\d\d\d\d\s\d\d+)')
    if ( $ismatch -ne $null -and $ismatch[0].Groups[1].Value)
    {
     $temp=Get-Content $filename | select -skip $i
     $filenametemp = $tempdir+"\temp.txt" #temp file path, don't change the filename "temp.txt"
     #$filename3 = $tempdir+"\test.txt"
     Add-Content $filenametemp $temp    

     $filename = $archivedirout+$prefix+"_"+$snaps[$i].Substring(8,2)+$snaps[$i].Substring(3,2)+$snaps[$i].Substring(0,2)+"_"+$snaps[$i].Substring(11,2)+$snaps[$i].Substring(14,2)+$snaps[$i].Substring(17,2)+".txt"
     
     $cmdOutput =  (cmd /c new_modified.exe $tempdir) | Out-String
     write-output $cmdOutput #"$cmdOutput is:" 
     #IF ([string]::IsNullOrWhitespace($cmdOutput)){
     # break
     #}
              
     $outData = $cmdOutput.Replace("xxx_xxx",$snaps[$i].Substring(6,4)+"-"+$snaps[$i].Substring(3,2)+"-"+$snaps[$i].Substring(0,2)+" "+$snaps[$i].Substring(11,8)+";")
       
     Add-Content $filename $outData
     remove-item -path $filenametemp
     
     
     break
     }
   }
   #break
  }
 else
  {
  write-host "waiting for file"
  }
Start-Sleep -s 30
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what is happening is that the output of the external program isn't being piped into a variable correctly.  I haven't had a chance to test this but `Tee-Object`  looks like the appropriate method for you.

I would suggest you try replacing...

```
$cmdOutput =  (cmd /c new_modified.exe $tempdir) | Out-String
```

with...

`cmd /c new_modified.exe $tempdir | Tee-Object -variable $cmdOutput`

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply!

I replaced that line of the code and now I receive a new error which says:

`Tee-Object: Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Variable' because it is null.`

Does this mean that MATLAB is not producing anything? If so, how do I see the output strings in the cmd window? Sorry if this sounds very basic!

Comment: sorry, should be 
`cmd /c new_modified.exe $tempdir | Tee-Object -variable cmdOutput`
I'm just too used to using a $ for all variables.

Comment: Thank you very very much for your help! It worked in the end, but I had to change one more thing at the MATLAB compiling stage (Not to suppress the console output checkbox.)

Comment: Good to hear.  If you think this answer was correct I would appreciate you marking it as such.  Thanks!